# how implement different module apk in one application?

Tags: android, apk

I have an application recipes and i would like to "connect" more expansion module.
For example , the main application have a main menu with an icon to a database of pastry recipe and if the user buy a new module(apk) from my google store page , the new module appear in the main menu, for example the new icon start a new program for chocolate recipes.
ho can connect different module in my main application?

thx a lot.

Comment: Using In-App purchase to unlock different features in one APK might be useful.

Comment: But it would have to encapsulate all resources in one apk. I have the same problem. And I should not push all those resources to the device unless the user buy/install all modules.